# How we can set multiple backgroud images in PDF with the jspdf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

I'm trying to set dynamic background images using the `npm jspdf package`. it's working for me all things but I can't set the dynamic background. I am trying to this way

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
const GanetatePdf = async(name="test.pdf",html) => {
    let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    let pWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.width; // 595.28 is the width of a4
    let srcWidth = html.scrollWidth;
    let margin = 10 // narrow margin - 1.27 cm (36);
    let scale = (pWidth - margin * 2) / srcWidth;

    pdf.html(html, {
        x: margin,
        y: margin,
        html2canvas: {
            scale: scale,
            allowTaint: true,
            backgroundColor: 'white'
        },
        callback: async function (doc) {
            //window.open(pdf.output('bloburl')); 
            let pageInfo = doc.internal.getCurrentPageInfo();
            let totalPages =  doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
            if(totalPages > 0 && totalPages > pageInfo.pageNumber){
              for(let p=totalPages;p>pageInfo.pageNumber;p--){
                doc.deletePage(p)
              }
            }      
            doc.save(name);
      
        },
        margin :[20, 0, 20, 0]
    });
  } 


   const html = (<div className='row mb-5 p-3 background-image' 
   style={{ backgroundImage: `url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSkxORFDMPY7v_DGrlgBxnFBHtwifP9Uz28Y5-8TcNpdTwILs3E')`, "background-repeat": "repeat-y" }}>
Hello World</div>)
   GanetatePdf(name="myfile.pdf",html);
```

Using this script I am able to create the pdf with images but the background images are not loaded.

Comment: @KJ Yes, JPEG images work after converting the base64, But my problem is it does not support the `background-image` property in the pdf so my image is not loaded. So I am finding any way to resolve this problem. I was finding a solution for resolving this issue but it is not working for me. Here is the URL to follow `https://jsfiddle.net/rmtest/30augcvj/2/`

Answer (score 0):

jsPDF repeatedly describe they will only work within a CORS limited environment so the majority of objects need to be inline, such as Fonts images and text. If you use a DataURL as base64 data that can significantly reduce problems.

[image]

here is similar in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pvqgcnfb/

system insists on code however I cannot link to full image so here it is broken

```
    <body id="pdf">
<!-- header section -->
<div class="section-header" id="main_d">
<h1>
data
</h1>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>

<script>

    var pdf = new jsPDF('1', 'pt', 'a4');
    pdf.addHTML($('#pdf')[0], function () {
       // pdf.output("dataurlnewwindow");
pdf.setFontSize(40);
pdf.setTextColor(255, 0, 0);
pdf.addImage("data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA0oAAAA8CAYAAABYSUqsAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAJRJSURBVHhe7b1llxzHmoV7f8 ...  wEFg4W7YiU6wgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==", "JPEG", 0, 20, 595, 60);
pdf.text("Octonyan loves jsPDF", 5, 60);
   pdf.save('Test.pdf');
 });


</script>
```